# MySql parametrized query with encryption resulting in incorrect sintax

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, syntax, prepared-statement

I have a table that store the login and password of users. For tests, the password is saved with extreme encryption.

Only for example: the password "one" is encrypted to

```
"[2hVFb>-@#+L4l!_N[1\\i=::3#n.-R$19Z[DgOKKk/X;81=h+Bor%3s:VS)q0-B]QX+%AQ6o`Vom##z=[\\od#ma*PT5\\)wU]{)J:I1JuZm$&?RQrrL{TSon`\"dGN\"fG[`%oSuohY4FVqPcmw%6EOU9bn\\B-4j]>4aTh/LV,;{Sm9`M%/x4.?y+2K4?-$-g0$^9AUqh.3UBZfdv0hF:zya|L&-\\wZh`\\Y=T2o8KHv0o>I0?+/xtdiCLWp,Y$=a>&rkj)n(+_-'AI->;|`4jfZq$\\;%|=/{C$lFvI0c%1yl>To&lWe8vBd%t+7%2QgU#s@O$Vh#l[JpO@/sJNBT\"hFf;,y\"NLstOLz_Q/{BMPq9UTfC^YH6(o*Z'(v83ncoUr{$23ZlJN*KMn2W+'$BX;koh?fG[G3KhA+f/qJa{#PsbrxmOT_E=O4`[.u\\tYo
zEkAH^`/iLApkzI!az^$MEW:-ihI>^v&onM?bWvNR%'|W[|K(KVUyL`KcQwA064pLwOjIPK:S[O1o>k'-x_QQE|B[vo1pL,%6v>Eb,Gf|*zxm?DVbkl;:Iii?4vo:KDPV@P7sPqy6xz>2>UUh,\\8{bDe05tW)\\ayH/:Ft/aA&k|]1x\"6j#NzHk_peGEXpwh6Y/93TCW9*'']U,/TmhQpr>+aBnhNHkH,LUi@Pn\"?rC;SO$aQumF;'7kENi$UaM\\EYUa:](E6'W*`bYMFFM{(3$a0oIGt((v|'!/"
```

This is how I'm verifying the login:

```
    internal static bool LoginValidation(string login, string password)
    {
        using (MySqlCommand sql = new MySqlCommand(" select count(*) from user where login = @login and password = @password ", myConnection))
        {
            sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
            sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
            sql.Connection.Open();
            return Convert.ToInt32(sql.ExecuteScalar()) > 0 ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

Where password is a string that contains the encrypted version of the user's password. The above code results in "incorrect sintax near password". Of course, the "password" parameter is not being parsed as expected. When I was using MS SQL Server, the above command works with no errors.

What I need to do to safely execute this query?

I also tried change the line

```
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
```

to

```
sql.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;
```

But without difference, resulting in incorrect syntax exception.

Comment: Go into Mysql and try running the query, replacing the parameters with their underlying values copied from VS. Result?

Comment: Will not work: there a lot of ' and other things that destroys the query. This is the problem: the parametrized query in MSSQL make the correct replaces to the query, and then executes correctly. How to make that to a MySql query?

Comment: Encryption is bad for passwords. You should be using a _hash_ instead.

Comment: Also, try a trailing semi-colon (;). MySql sometimes requires that.

Comment: Depending on the version of MySQL you may or may not need to change placeholder character  from `@` to `?` or tune connection parameters.